# Cannot retrieve a Google Profile for editing

Tags: c#, google-apps

I'm trying to retrieve a Google Profile for editing from the Profile API using the C# .NET GData SDK but authentication seems to be failing. I'm using a number of other Google API's and can authenticate with them just fine and am using the same code approach:

```
var settings = new RequestSettings("appname", ApiUsername, ApiPassword);
var contactsRequest = new ContactsRequest(settings);
var uri = new Uri(string.Format("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/profiles/domain/{0}/full/{1}", googleDomain, googleUsername));
var contact = contactsRequest.Retrieve<Contact>(uri);
```

I get the following exception:

> Google.GData.Client.GDataRequestException: Execution of request
>   failed:
>   https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/profiles/domain/xxx/full/joe.bloggs
>   ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

On the advice of Google Enterprise support I used their OAuth2 Playground site using the same credentials as in the code and it worked.

My guess is that the SDK whilst taking in a username and password does not use these credentials in the RequestSettings object and authentication is failing, even though this same approach works on their Provisioning API.

My fear is that I need to use OAuth2, which seems unecessarily complicated for what we're trying to do and there's no Google documentation to support this.

Does anyone have any code examples of how to authenticate with the Profiles API?

**Edit:**

So yes, it seems I have to use OAuth2 and the Google SDK is broken as it doesn't allow you to just use username and password to authenticate. I've been hacking around with a lot of examples and am using another Google SDK that offers OAuth2 support.

I've created a Client ID for installed applications via the API console, assigned this id API access to the scope and am using the following code:

```
var oAuth2Parameters = new OAuth2Parameters
{
    ClientId = "xxx",
    ClientSecret = "xxx",
    RedirectUri = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob",
    Scope = "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/"
};

// get an access token
OAuthUtil.GetAccessToken(oAuth2Parameters);

var settings = new RequestSettings("xxx", oAuth2Parameters);
var contactsRequest = new ContactsRequest(settings);
```

This gets me further along, but now I get the following exception:

> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name:
>   refresh_token

This code is running as part of a back-end service. I don't know if the client id type of Installed Application is wrong for the type of authentication exchange. My first thought was to use the Service Account client id type, but this produced a certificate which isn't usable by the OAuth2Parameters object.

Any helpful pointers?

Answer (score 0):

I am retagging this to google-apps from google-apps-script (Cloud based JavaScript).

Regarding your question - yes, you'll need to use oAuth 2 but oAuth 2 itself gives you some options. Once you spend a few hours understanding it - it will really pay off as it is becoming very standard and commonplace across many vendors.

Google offers several starter libraries (including .NET) to get you started here - https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2#libraries

Try some of that out and share if you run into any issues.

Comment: Arun, I was told by Google Enterprise Support to tag it that way so they would see it and answer it. Thanks for your reply all the same. I've updated my question above...

Answer (score 0):

After much experimenting, I've got the results back from the Profile API I need without using OAuth2, which was way too much of a headache (mainly because of the poor quality of the Google SDK and their documentation, the concept is simple enough).

I used the simple username & password authentication method and instead of using ContactsRequest.Retrieve(uri) I used:

```
var settings = new RequestSettings("xxx", ApiUsername, ApiPassword);
var cr = new ContactsRequest(settings);
var uri = new Uri(string.Format("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/profiles/domain/{0}/full/{1}", googleDomain, googleUsername));
var query = new ContactsQuery(uri.AbsoluteUri);
var feed = cr.Get<Contact>(query);
```